# getElementById after input new elemet

Tags: angular, typescript

1.I got new data from server and I inputed new elemet(treeNodes) to the page with new data.

2.I get all id of treeNodes. The new id of new treeNodes I founded well.

3.Finally I call last fuction where in foreach I finde all treeNodes with getElementById().

```
this.apiService.tree().subscribe(
  suc => {
    this.addCodeToNode(event, suc); // 1
    event.node.data[0].loading = false;

    const idChildArray: Array<string> = []; // 2
    event.node.children.forEach(element => {
      idChildArray.push(String(element.data[0].id));
    });
    this.moveRightChildrenNodes(idChildArray); // 3
  },
  err => {
    event.node.data[0].loading = false;
  }
);
```

Last function

```
moveRightChildrenNodes(idChildArray: Array<string>) {
idChildArray.forEach(id => {
  const parentTitle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(id);
  console.log(id, parentTitle); // here I see all elements but new nodes from server
  const divNodeForPad = parentTitle.closest('li > div') as HTMLElement;
  divNodeForPad.setAttribute('style', 'padding-left: 20px !important');
});
}
```

If I harcorde to code of new Id I will founde it only in next call of method.

Comment: Try to use ViewChild/ViewChildren instead of `document.getElementById`. This is an intended way of working with html elements in angular

Comment: why are you manipulating the DOM like this? I would say it's not the "angular way". Use angular bindings instead.

Comment: I need use it on function. This case I must it declair on the start on Component.